# How to run Selenium with Webdriver on Online Python interpreters?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pythoninterpreter, replit

Folks, I have a scraping script that I need to run on specific times for live info, but I can't have my computer on me all day. So I thought about running it on an online interpreter, but repl.it doesn't have webdriver and the other I found didn't neither. Could you help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I don't guess if you can do it on a free online interpreter!

You can buy a server and use that, You can SSH to it anytime you want, or even better, You can develop a micro web service using Flask or something else to report the data you need!

Other way I can think of is let your computer be online 24/7 and use `smtplib` to email yourself the data in an interval!